# "Ends in" grammar rules

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

I know if a subject is singular and we're talking about something that is continuous we put an "s" after end like:

> This is what the suffering ends in.

But what if the subject is plural? Like:

> This is what winter streets end in.

Is my sentence correct?

Comment: I don't get what you mean there! 'ends in' always talk about the ***results***. What results you are talking about especially for those 'winter streets'

Comment: Neither one of those sentences are understandable. (I am a native American English speaker)

Comment: @avid19: _is_ understandable.

Comment: @Ricky To be fair, constructions like this (especially *none are*) are quite common in colloquial English, despite being "incorrect".

Comment: @Era: "None are" _is_, in fact, correct. Not every time, though.

Comment: @Ricky that's my point. What avid19 said is perfectly fine, just colloquial. It's only "incorrect" to prescriptivists.

Comment: Ricky's comment above can be disregarded.

Comment: Both your sentences are correct. Your main clause "This is" contains the subject "This" and the verb "is." The predicate nominative after the linking verb "is" is a noun dependent clause in both sentences. "what" introduces the clause and also serves the purpose of being the object of the preposition "in." It's antecedent is the subject of the sentence pronoun "This." *This = what = the suffering ends in what = the suffering ends in this* Same for other sentence "...winter streets end in this." As for the Subject/Verb agreement...[Con't]

Comment: "suffering ends" and "streets end" is correct. suffering = singular / ends = singular AND  streets = plural / end = plural. By the way, both sentences are Simple Sentences with one subject and one verb, the noun dependent clause does not make it a Complex Sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is correct.

*End in* is particular verb phrase that means:

> Have as its final part or result

See the entry for *[end](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/end?q=end+in#end__26)* in the Oxford Dictionary.

So, the verb phrase follows the normal rule for subject/verb agreement. A singular subject takes a singular verb, and a plural subject takes a plural verb. For present tense regular verbs, the only person & number that *ends in* ***S*** is the third person singular. All the others do not require an *S*.

Since *winter streets* is third person, plural, you do not add an *S* to the verb to make it plural.

Answer (score 0):

Both example sentences are grammatically correct, but neither one makes much sense.

In answer to your question, it follows the ordinary rule for subject-verb agreement: typically, a singular subject uses a verb ending in -s and a plural subject uses a verb without the -s (in the present tense).

> That man runs a mile every morning.
>
> Those women run a mile a day.

The verb *to end* is not special in this case.